# When i try sending message to channel i receive HTTP unauthorized error?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying to use the below Graph API call, sending message to a given channel as per Microsoft Documentation. But i receive HTTP unauthorized error. Please help.

`POST /teams/{team-id}/channels/{channel-id}/messages`

Comment: (1) I tested the above Graph API call with Graph Explorer/POSTMAN and it works for me. So try the same to see if you can isolate the issue outside of your application (2) Share the graph response output (requestid, timestamp)

Comment: Not sure what is different or how it makes difference. But i will try with POSTMAN.

Comment: From my application i see this: 

Requestid - 6f7eae28-fefe-43a5-a5cf-51f6eb396ae9, timestamp - 2021-06-30T09:58:22, HTTP error - Unauthorized

Comment: ok @Tsang, i tested with delegated permissions and it worked for me. I believe you're using it with application permissions and observing this issue. Unfortunately with application permissions its not supported. Here's the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) talks about the same.

Comment: Consider [filing Microsoft 365 Developer Platform idea/uservoice](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) - so that Microsoft Teams can consider implementing it.

Comment: Yes @Dev you're SPOT-ON. When I tried with application permissions i got the error. When i tested with POSTMAN, delegated permission it and works. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234533/discussion-between-tsang-so-and-dev).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested with delegated permissions and it worked. When you tested with with application permissions, you observed the issue. Because at this point application permissions is not supported. Here's the [documentation talks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) about the same. Hence consider [filing Microsoft 365 Developer Platform idea/uservoice](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) so that Microsoft Teams can consider implementing it.